# Creating a date from a timestamp

Tags: php, date, php-7

I have the following timestamp:
2842214400

Using the online conversion tool http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm
This gives the date of

Sun, 25 Jan 2060 00:00:00 GMT

However using the following code:

```
$timestamp = 2842214400;
print date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

In PHP 5.6.30 gives a result of 1923-12-19 17:31:44

In PHP 7.0.15 gives a result of FALSE

What am i doing wrong here? Neither PHP results are what i would expect?

Comment: Could it be the [Y2K38](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) problem? Are both PHP versions compiled as 64-bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
var_dump(PHP_INT_SIZE === 8;
```

If it returns TRUE, use the DateTime  class (http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) instead of the standard date functions.

If it returns FALSE, you are running a 32-bit version of php. You either need to switch to 64-bit or use an outside library like ADO (http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/adodb_date_library).

Comment: @RobHolmes I'm glad my answer was helpful. Please accept it as the answer.